# the apk packaged by UE4 can not run successfully on Android 6.0

Tags: android-6.0-marshmallow, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I have encountered this kind of problems, when I use Unreal Engine 4(UE4) to develop an easy demo game in Android 6.0 platform. That is when I try to open the app created by UE4,I have got an error, the app splashes and close. 
  I try to logcat the msg generated by mobile device, however, I do not get non of useful msg about this error.

The following is an extract of msg:

0-21 17:23:20.399 I/System.out( 2869): Calling by::className:com.huawei.lcagent.util.FileUtils  MethodName:runCommand
10-21 17:23:20.404 W/InputDispatcher( 1012): channel 'f8effe com.manchoose.paocar/com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-21 17:23:20.404 E/InputDispatcher( 1012): channel 'f8effe com.manchoose.paocar/com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-21 17:23:20.404 W/InputDispatcher( 1012): channel 'd21f9f3 com.manchoose.paocar/com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
10-21 17:23:20.404 E/InputDispatcher( 1012): channel 'd21f9f3 com.manchoose.paocar/com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
10-21 17:23:20.404 I/Zygote  (  550): Process 16912 exited due to signal (11)
10-21 17:23:20.405 W/InputDispatcher( 1012): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'f8effe com.manchoose.paocar/com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity (server)'
10-21 17:23:20.406 E/HsmCoreServiceImpl( 1012): onTransact in code is: 102
10-21 17:23:20.406 I/MediaProcessHandler( 1012): processOp opType: 1, uid: 10167, pid: 16912
10-21 17:23:20.406 W/MediaProcessHandler( 1012): remove target not exist, maybe the UI process: uid: 10167, pid: 16912
10-21 17:23:20.408 W/InputDispatcher( 1012): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'd21f9f3 com.manchoose.paocar/com.epicgames.ue4.GameActivity (server)'
10-21 17:23:20.416 E/PackageLogInfoManager( 2869): checkPackageLogState, cr: android.app.ContextImpl$ApplicationContentResolver@f3414db, packageNames: null
10-21 17:23:20.419 I/gralloc (  382): Alloc req: dev=0x7f87342540, w=1440, h=2560, format=0x1, usage=0xb33
10-21 17:23:20.419 I/gralloc (  382): Alloc handle(0x7f68620300): interfmt=0x1, stride=1472, size=15310848
10-21 17:23:20.421 W/gralloc (  382): gralloc_register_buffer:74: Registering handle 0x7f68620200 coming from the same process: 382.
10-21 17:23:20.443 I/InputReader( 1012): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
10-21 17:23:20.443 I/InputReader( 1012): Device reconfigured: id=2, name='huawei,touchscreen', size 1080x1920, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
10-21 17:23:20.444 I/InputReader( 1012): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000004
10-21 17:23:20.448 I/HwSystemManager( 1794): HsmPackageManager:onConfigureChanged: zh_CN
10-21 17:23:20.449 I/HwSystemManager( 6680): HsmPackageManager:onConfigureChanged: zh_CN
10-21 17:23:20.450 I/HwEmailTag( 6457): ImmersionStyleHelper->resetStatusForImmersionStyle()
10-21 17:23:20.450 I/HwEmailTag( 6457): EmailApplication->onConfigurationChanged
10-21 17:23:20.473 I/gralloc (  382): Free handle(0x7f68620400)
10-21 17:23:20.473 I/gralloc (  382): Free handle(0x7f87488e00)

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with this on 4.13 - a hotfix was released that should have fixed it.  If you have not already try and upgrade to the latest version.